# Missing events when querying from Calendar API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm noticing that not all calendar events are returned when querying for events.

Using Graph Explorer, I used this query to look for all events within the Canada Holidays calendar.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/{canada-holidays-calendar-id}/events?$select=subject,start`

Which returned:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('d0418d55-79af-4f7f-8fab-239421c2ef1c')/calendars('AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAAAAAEGAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABontjAAA%3D')/events(subject,start)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAAAAAEGAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABontjAAA=/events?$select=subject%2cstart&$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OMQ==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAlAAA=",
            "subject": "Boxing Day Bank Holiday",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-12-28T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OMA==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAkAAA=",
            "subject": "Thanksgiving Day",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-10-12T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OLw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAjAAA=",
            "subject": "Labour Day",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-09-07T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OLg==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAiAAA=",
            "subject": "Discovery Day (Yukon)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-17T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OLQ==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAhAAA=",
            "subject": "New Brunswick Day (New Brunswick)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OLA==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAgAAA=",
            "subject": "British Columbia Day (British Columbia)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OKw==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAfAAA=",
            "subject": "Heritage Day (Alberta)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OKg==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAeAAA=",
            "subject": "Civic Holiday (many provinces)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OKQ==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAdAAA=",
            "subject": "Natal Day (Nova Scotia and PEI)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-08-03T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"4muWeuOXaUaPUVEWnMxoYgAAAZ5OKA==\"",
            "id": "AAMkADI1MWIxYjdmLWQxNGUtNGQ2OS05NDM0LTdjNTk0Yjg1YjlhYQBGAAAAAAAIvIPbe2IQQZqhtkkXQti2BwDia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABoWyIAADia5Z645dpRo9RURaczGhiAAABooAcAAA=",
            "subject": "Orangemen's Day (Newfoundland and Labrador)",
            "start": {
                "dateTime": "2026-07-13T00:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, there are missing events here. Ex: Remembrance Day in November, or Christmas Days and New Year's Eve in December, and possibly others. However, these events do exist within my Outlook calendar as well as when queried by name using this query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{canada-holidays-calendar-id}/events?$filter=subject eq 'New Year''s Eve'`

I thought it could be a paging thing where the results are placed in later pages, so I decided to query for events in December 2026

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/{canada-holidays-calendar-id}/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2026-12-01T00:00' and end/dateTime le '2026-12-31T23:59'`

but it still only return the Boxing Day event above. In fact, I tried looking for events in December 2023 using the same query but it returned an empty list.

I queried for events within my personal calendar as well and noticed the same thing; certain events are missing while other events outside of my time frame were included in the result. Some of these events are recurring events and some were from invitations that I accepted so I'm not sure how they would be treated.

So yeah, I'm not sure what's going on here, though I think the issue is most likely with how I'm querying these events. My ultimate goal is to be able to query for events in a calendar between some date time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a CalendarView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http as this will ensure that any recurring events (including modified occurrence and deletions) will be expanded.